# Finding out which row has been updated/deleted JDBC (ResultSet)

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, resultset

I am writing an application which needs to keep some metadata about the rows of the underlying MySQL server (it communicates with the MySQL server via the JDBC driver).

Effectively, each client has a unique ID and my Java application needs to store, for each row,the uuid of the last client who modified the row.

So far, when a row is inserted I allocate it a slot in a metadata table referenced by its primary key.

The only way I can think of doing this is doing a select on the table (with the same where condition as the update/delete), but this imply that for a given query I'm effectively doubling the work. Does have any better ideas, or known of a JDBC way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches to updating data in SQL from Java:

1. Keep all the logic in Java as you are doing, this keeps the tables simple and all your logic in the code
2. Write a stored procedure in MySQL to do the updates on the other tables when the change occurs. If you follow this route then the Java code is simple but the logic on the tables is complicated in SQL

What you should not do is split the difference and have some of the logic in Java and some in SQL. I recommend sticking with your approach because it's much harder to modify and debug stored procedure code in SQL than in Java.

PS I have done this both ways, keeping the logic in Java is much easier to maintain.

Comment: Right, I'm keeping the logic in Java anyways, but would rather not have, for every "update * where x= ", also have to do a "select * where x" and was wondering if there was a preexisintg jdbc function that did that in a more efficient way

Comment: I don't think JDBC provides functions like the one you want. The JDBC code is just a thin wrapper over an SQL connection with a few utilities to help you send queries and receive rows and errors.